# How to make scrollable panel in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, scrollbar

I need to make timeline like this http://image.ohozaa.com/i/g07/tEmBWw.png
this panel generated by database.

User can edit tasking time by hold click on a pin and slide until mouse up.
What should i do?